# Does the golang `range` keyword botch uint type information?

Tags: go

Consider this golang program:

```go
func main() {
    one := uint(1)
    ones := []uint{1, 1, 1}
    for x := range ones {
        if x != one {
            print("ERR")
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile I get an unexpected error:

```
$ go build foo.go 
# command-line-arguments
./foo.go:7: invalid operation: x != one (mismatched types int and uint)
```

Why does go think `x` has type `int` instead of `uint`?

Comment: `range` is not an operator but a keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first value returned by `range` is the index, not the value. What you need is:

```
func main() {
    one := uint(1)
    ones := []uint{1, 1, 1}
    for _, x := range ones {
        if x != one {
            print("ERR")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But still, shouldn't the index also be an `uint` ?

Comment: @Anubis Indices are usually `int` so that you could use negative values for special cases. E.g. a search function can return `-1` as index if a value was not found.

Comment: yeah i get that, but that's the something decided inside a function. But i think, for example, range can't return a negative index at any time (at least for an array) right? If that is true, then what is the point of keeping a signed data type? (Sorry, I'm very new to Go language, maybe I'm overlooking something)

Comment: @Anubis Basically it's to make life easier for everyone. If it was `int` *unless in range,* that would be confusing. So most programming language designers simply decide to make all array indices `int` and not think too much about it. In a language with [ADTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type), like Rust, indices are actually often `uint`, and an ADT is used to return absence of a value.